# Как решить ошибку с импортом шаблона Brandstore

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

cms wordpress, тема установлена Astra и плагин элементор. При импорте шаблона Brandstore появляется ошибка -
Import Process Interrupted

We are facing a temporary issue in importing this template.

Read article to resolve the issue and continue importing template.

Comment: "Мы столкнулись с временной проблемой при импорте этого шаблона"

Comment: Она не носит временный характер как я понял

Comment: проблема может быть в чем угодно, обратитесь к разработчику плагина или сюда https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/